# Why are these resistors used? What is their function in this BQ76920 circuit?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, circuit-analysis, pcb, bms

[image]

I am designing a BMS using a TI BQ76920 connected to an ATmega328P via I2C. I'm using the design in the datasheet as my reference. I am confused about why and how these resistors are being used in the circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's explained on p.23 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76940.pdf):

[image]

Comment: yes I read that but i am unable to understand why this value (1M) ,why we require high impedance path ,if we want to pull it down quickly shouldn't we have low impedance path ,right?

Comment: @navi the datasheet mentions of a load detection sub-circuit connected to CHG pin, to detect if PACK– node is at an abnormally high voltage (see 8.3.1.3.2 at p.24). R1 and R2 seem to be a current limiting resistor pair for this detection sub-circuit. As you can see, when the CHG pin is at low (=0) current will flow through R2 (neglecting the zener for a moment), R1, and body diode of Q3 if PACK– voltage is high. And you don't want to load the PACK– voltage with low value resistors, do you?

Comment: Oh ok Thank you I got it.